# ASP.NET MVC 3 RAZOR Style

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

how to use style block in a view ?

```
@<Style>
...
</Style>
```

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a RenderSection in the head of your Layout, then add section to that content in a view.  See this article: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx

(Hopefully this will help the next Google visitor who gets this unanswered question first.)

Answer (score 1):

style block only valid under <head> tag. if u use master page, just add content template in <head> tag

As the example:

```
<head>
    <style>
    ...
    </style>
</head>
```